# Probability course question

Tags: probability

If 30% of students in a physics class also take a calculus course & further assume that
P(“earn A in physics”|”taking calculus”) = .4, P(“earn A in physics”|”not taking calculus”) = .1
If a student earns an A in physics what is the probability said student is taking calculus?

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: @Daryl I'm not sure if I'm plugging them in correctly. You don't have to do math but can you set up problem for me?

Comment: I think it is ${12\over19}\approx0.631$. Anon did a good job below.

Answer (score 2):

$C$ = "taking calculus"

$C^c$ = "not taking calculus"

$A$ = "earns A in physics"

You want to find $P(C|A)$

Bayes' Theorem =  $P(C|A)$  = $\dfrac{P(A|C)P(C)}{P(A)}$

Law of Total Probability: $P(A)$ = $P(A|C)P(C) + P(A|C^c)P(C^c)$

$P(C)$ = .3

$P(C^c)$ = .7

$P(A|C)$ = .4

$P(A|C^c)$ = .1

Comment: I got 0.63157894736. Just wanted to see if you would please work thru so I can compare my answer to yours